# In WebAPI, FormsAuthentication does not seem to remember cookie

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my webAPI I have a call to the controller that does

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Username, true);
```

but the cookies don't seem to set.

Is there a way to get this to happen in webAPI? I know there is know system.web so maybe that is my issue (but the call is there)

Comment: Is everything within the same domain?

Comment: Should work. Have you set the Authentication Mode to Forms in the web.config?

Comment: Yup, that was it. thought Forms was default configuration.  I should have checked that.  Thanks SimonC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimonC hit it on the head with Auth Mode